# Jenkins: Gerrit event trigger plugin

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

Need some help.
 Do we have any option to filter specific users for Gerrit event plugin.
currently its triggering for all which i don't want to  trigger for every one in the team.

Comment: Are you using the Gerrit Trigger plugin on Jenkins?

Comment: thanks for reply .                                                                                                     yes,im using gerrit trigger plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure the Gerrit Trigger plugin to trigger only for some specific users but you can use a workaround to accomplish something like this.

When the job is triggered by Gerrit Trigger plugin some environment variables are automatically set. The more useful in your case are:

- GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_NAME
- GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_EMAIL
- GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_NAME
- GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_EMAIL
- GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_NAME
- GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL

You can check some of these variables and abort the build if he/she isn't one of the specific users.